# The called python file won't show again

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having problem calling the file `online.py`.

Code:

```
# For Face_recognition
from logging import disable
import tkinter
from tkinter.font import BOLD
from cv2 import data
import numpy as np
import face_recognition as fr
import cv2

# SQL-CONNECTOR
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import IntegrityError

# For Trainer
import PIL.Image
import os
from tkinter import ttk

# GUI
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


# USER INTERFACE
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("FACEREGISTRATION SYSTEM")
window.resizable(0,0)
# bgs = PhotoImage(file = "C://Users//So_Low//Desktop//final_recog//online_reg_img/edited2.png")
# labels1 = Label(window, image = bgs)
# labels1.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth= 1, relheight= 1)



# UPPER DESIGN
l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "N O R M I",  font=("Exton Free Trial",35), fg='green')
l1.grid(column = 2, row= 1)



# TEXT BOXES
l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "Name",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
l1.grid(column = 1, row=3)
on1 = tk.Entry(window, width=40, bd=3)
on1.grid(column=2, row=3)

l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "Parent/Visitor",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
l1.grid(column = 1, row=5)
on2 = tk.Entry(window, width=40, bd=3)
on2.grid(column= 2, row=5)

l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "Relationship",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
l1.grid(column = 1, row=6)
on3 = tk.Entry(window, width=40, bd=3)
on3.grid(column= 2, row=6)

l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "ID",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
l1.grid(column = 1, row=7)
on4 = tk.Entry(window, width=19, bd=3, bg="light blue")
on4.grid(column=2, row=7)

l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "Address",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
l1.grid(column = 1, row=8)
on5 = tk.Entry(window, width=40, bd=3)
on5.grid(column= 2, row=8)

l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "Contact #",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
l1.grid(column = 1, row=9)
on6 = tk.Entry(window, width=20, bd=3, bg = "light blue")
on6.grid(column= 2, row=9)

def onregister():
    if (on1.get()==""  or on2.get()=="" or on3.get()=="" or on4.get()=="" or on5.get()=="" or on6.get()==""):
        messagebox.showinfo("Result","Please Complete the Provided Details!")
    else:
        databases = mysql.connector.connect(
        host ="localhost",
        user = "userdata",
        password = "",
        database = "facerecog"
        )

        cursors = databases.cursor()
        cursors.execute("SELECT * from record")
        result = cursors.fetchall()


        id= on4.get()
        id = int(id)+1
        id
        sql = "INSERT INTO record(ids, names,course_year,positions,addresses,contact) values(%s ,%s ,%s , %s, %s, %s)"
        val = (id, on1.get(), on2.get(), on3.get(), on5.get(), on6.get())
        try:
            cursors.execute(sql,val)
            databases.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","ID Is Already Exist")
            return onregister
        finally:
            cursors.close()
            databases.close()

        on2.delete(0,END)
        on3.delete(0,END)
        on4.delete(0,END)
        on5.delete(0,END)
        on6.delete(0,END)

        DirPath = "C:/Users/So_Low/Desktop/final_recog/online_reg_img/"
        Files = os.listdir(DirPath)

        for File in Files:
            imgPath = os.path.join(DirPath, File)
            image = cv2.imread(imgPath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/So_Low/Desktop/final_recog/img/"+str (on1.get())+"." +str(id)+".jpg",image)
            
btns1 = tk.Button(window,text= "Save To Database", font=("Bahnschrift",15),bg="light blue",fg="black",command=onregister)
btns1.grid(column=2,row=40)
l1 = tk.Label(window, text= " ",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
l1.grid(column = 2, row=35)

window.geometry("500x400")
window.mainloop()
```

I'm importing it in my other code by calling this function:

```
def onreg():
    import online
    online
    return online

btn1 = tk.Button(window,text= "Online Register", font=("Bahnschrift",15),bg="light blue",fg="black",command=onreg)
btn1.grid(column=1,row=35)
```

It shows when I click the button but when I close the called file and click it again it won't open. And there's no error showing. How could I show it when I called it again?

Comment: Don't post images or links to code or error messages. Include them into the question as text, properly formatted in a code block.

Comment: ohw sorry a lot my friend I just gonna edit it @TedKleinBergman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules in Python are not supposed to be run multiple times, they are supposed to be a way of defining variables to be used in other scripts. Therefore importing a module twice does not run it twice; the interpreter stores the variables from the module the first time it is run, and if you try to import it again it will give you the variables it already has stored and not run the file again.

There are a few ways of getting around this; here are two of them:

1. Put the code in the module into a function, and import that function:

   ```py
   # online.py (module):
   def online():
       ...  # code to be run

   # Registers.py (main script):
   import online  # at start of file
   ...  # some code
   ...  # get rid of the onreg() function, it is not necessary
   btn1 = tk.Button(..., command=online.online)  # Line where button is created
   ...  # rest of code
   ```
2. Alternatively, if this is not possible for whatever reason, use the `importlib` library to `reload()` the module which will run it again:

   ```py
   # online.py (module) stays the same

   # Registers.py (main script):
   import importlib  # at start of file
   online_module = None  # at start of file, just after imports, call this variable whatever you want
   ...  # some code
   def onreg():  # redo this function
       global online_module
       try:
           importlib.reload(online_module)
       except TypeError:
           import online_module
   ...  # rest of code stays the same
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Programs will only be imported once, so the code won't run again if you try to import it again. Instead, put all the code you want to be run multiple times into a function, instead of a module.

Here's a very simple solution, but not a very good one.

```py
# For Face_recognition
from logging import disable
import tkinter
from tkinter.font import BOLD
from cv2 import data
import numpy as np
import face_recognition as fr
import cv2

# SQL-CONNECTOR
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import IntegrityError

# For Trainer
import PIL.Image
import os
from tkinter import ttk

# GUI
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def create_window():
    # USER INTERFACE
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("FACEREGISTRATION SYSTEM")
    window.resizable(0,0)
    # bgs = PhotoImage(file = "C://Users//So_Low//Desktop//final_recog//online_reg_img/edited2.png")
    # labels1 = Label(window, image = bgs)
    # labels1.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth= 1, relheight= 1)
    
    
    
    # UPPER DESIGN
    l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "N O R M I",  font=("Exton Free Trial",35), fg='green')
    l1.grid(column = 2, row= 1)
    
    
    
    # TEXT BOXES
    l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "Name",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
    l1.grid(column = 1, row=3)
    on1 = tk.Entry(window, width=40, bd=3)
    on1.grid(column=2, row=3)
    
    l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "Parent/Visitor",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
    l1.grid(column = 1, row=5)
    on2 = tk.Entry(window, width=40, bd=3)
    on2.grid(column= 2, row=5)
    
    l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "Relationship",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
    l1.grid(column = 1, row=6)
    on3 = tk.Entry(window, width=40, bd=3)
    on3.grid(column= 2, row=6)
    
    l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "ID",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
    l1.grid(column = 1, row=7)
    on4 = tk.Entry(window, width=19, bd=3, bg="light blue")
    on4.grid(column=2, row=7)
    
    l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "Address",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
    l1.grid(column = 1, row=8)
    on5 = tk.Entry(window, width=40, bd=3)
    on5.grid(column= 2, row=8)
    
    l1 = tk.Label(window, text= "Contact #",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
    l1.grid(column = 1, row=9)
    on6 = tk.Entry(window, width=20, bd=3, bg = "light blue")
    on6.grid(column= 2, row=9)
    
    def onregister():
        if (on1.get()==""  or on2.get()=="" or on3.get()=="" or on4.get()=="" or on5.get()=="" or on6.get()==""):
            messagebox.showinfo("Result","Please Complete the Provided Details!")
        else:
            databases = mysql.connector.connect(
            host ="localhost",
            user = "userdata",
            password = "",
            database = "facerecog"
            )
    
            cursors = databases.cursor()
            cursors.execute("SELECT * from record")
            result = cursors.fetchall()
    
    
            id= on4.get()
            id = int(id)+1
            id
            sql = "INSERT INTO record(ids, names,course_year,positions,addresses,contact) values(%s ,%s ,%s , %s, %s, %s)"
            val = (id, on1.get(), on2.get(), on3.get(), on5.get(), on6.get())
            try:
                cursors.execute(sql,val)
                databases.commit()
            except IntegrityError:
                messagebox.showinfo("Error","ID Is Already Exist")
                return onregister
            finally:
                cursors.close()
                databases.close()
    
            on2.delete(0,END)
            on3.delete(0,END)
            on4.delete(0,END)
            on5.delete(0,END)
            on6.delete(0,END)
    
            DirPath = "C:/Users/So_Low/Desktop/final_recog/online_reg_img/"
            Files = os.listdir(DirPath)
    
            for File in Files:
                imgPath = os.path.join(DirPath, File)
                image = cv2.imread(imgPath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/So_Low/Desktop/final_recog/img/"+str (on1.get())+"." +str(id)+".jpg",image)
                
    btns1 = tk.Button(window,text= "Save To Database", font=("Bahnschrift",15),bg="light blue",fg="black",command=onregister)
    btns1.grid(column=2,row=40)
    l1 = tk.Label(window, text= " ",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
    l1.grid(column = 2, row=35)
    
    window.geometry("500x400")
    window.mainloop()
```

And in your other code:

```py
# This won't run anything anymore. It'll just define the function `create_window`.
import online

# We also don't need the function `onreg`. We can use `online.create_window` directly instead.
button1 = tk.Button(window, text="Online Register", font=("Bahnschrift",15), bg="light blue", fg="black", command=online.create_window)
button1.grid(column=1, row=35)
```

Comment: If I don't use function how could it put it on a button? Cause I am running 2 window's and If someone register's online. then click the button. I tried your answer it work's but it shows simultaneously

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You have to use a function as a command for the button.

Comment: Yes your right sir  need to use button to execute the command because I am not only running online.py window, I also have register's window. I call the online.py when it needed. I tried your  code to put on function but I got error when I call again it says like this "AttributeError: partially initialized module 'online' has no attribute 'create_window' (most likely due to a circular import) "

Comment: @ewan_wabalo That sounds like you have multiple files that are importing from each other (circular import). I can't say exactly what the problem is because it's in one of your other files. So make sure you're not importing things in functions (like you did previously) but instead import everything you need at the top of your files (like you do in your first code example), and also make sure that you don't have modules that depend on each other. For example, register -> online -> register, or something similar.

Comment: I see it now I just rename the online.py into onlines.py so the error solved. Thanks a Lot for the Help.